# How to change default FontSize unit

Tags: wpf, xaml, font-size, visual-studio-2015

I'm playing around in the new version of `Visual Studio 2015 (Community)`.

I notice that that in the XAML designer, the default unit qualifier for `FontSize` is `Pt (point)`.

However I want to have `Px (pixel)` as a default (like the previous VS editions).

I looked around in the settings of VS, but i can't seem to find any option to change this.

Anyone has an idea how to change this?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.size(v=vs.110).aspx

The 'Font.Size' Property is not having any changes in VS 2015.

Comment: The only units you can change in Visual Studio 2015 is in Options -> Web Forms Designer -> Ruler and Grid

Comment: It's not possible. How hard is it to write "px"?

Answer (score 0):

WPF defaults to px. To force WPF to use a different unit of measurement, just append the unit abbreviation to the FontSize.

```
FontSize="24px"
```