# How to change the font size unit in the properties window in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp

[image: I want to change the unit from px to pt]

How can I change the font size unit from px to pt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31689239/6835535), you can directly write `15 pt` in there. If its WPF, you can also write it directly in xaml.